# How do I check my root url in flask without making any request?

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a flask api separately in both a development and a production server. Naturally both apps should acess different adresses and databases, so it is important that the code self identifys if it its being running in the dev. url or the prod. url.

I know that I can use request.root_url, but this only works inside callables, and I must acess this information before letting anyone making requests to my app.

thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request), and then utilize `request.root_url`?

Comment: hum thats interessing, but idk if it solves my problem. I don't need to run this function everytime before every request (it would be costly to run all databases everytime). I need to check where the script is being running in once